# JQuery plugin to transform with user interface

Tags: jquery, interface, transform

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that adds an interface to images to turn, scale, rotate and move with dots in the corners, like in photoshop and other image manipulation software..

I came across something like this when I didn't need it, and now that I need it I just can't find it. The only thing I found is this:

http://www.egrappler.com/contents/SmartIt/Demo/smartit.htm

It looks nice, and is exactly what I need, but it's a little buggy with the rotation.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one project I used css property "transform" for this purpose:

```
var rotate = function(degree)
{
   ...
   oSelf.css({
      'transform' : 'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
      '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
      '-o-transform' : 'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
      '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+degree+'deg)',
      '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+degree+'deg)'
   });
}
```

As usually it [doesn't work](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) in IE8 and earlier.

But IMHO [this library](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/) has prettier rendering that native browser rendering.

And one more [sample of editing picture](http://vremenno.net/examples/jquery-ui-rotation/) but it uses old libraries

Comment: Hey Denis, great answer, thanks! I don't need support for IE, thank god! What I do need is the interface, like in the sample, which works good in Chrome.. So I'll use that!